# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'UserId'. (other questions have been read already)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi everyone I am trying to add a dropdownlist to my create view that will contain a list of all users in the distributee role I was sure I had set this up correctly but any time I attempt to open the create page I receive 
{"There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'UserId'."}

controller method

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Document Author")]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "DocumentID,DocTitle,RevisionNumber,DocumentAuthor,CreationDate,ActivationDate,DocumentStatus,FilePath,Distributee") ] Document document, HttpPostedFileBase file, object selectedName = null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    string _FileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    string _path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"), _FileName);
                    file.SaveAs(_path);

                    document.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
                    document.ActivationDate = DateTime.Now;
                    document.DocumentAuthor = User.Identity.Name;
                    document.DocumentStatus = "Draft";
                    document.FilePath = _path;
                }
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                    ViewBag.Message = "File Uploaded Successfully!!";
                    db.Documents.Add(document);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");  
                    }
            }
            catch
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "File upload failed!!";
                return View(document);
            }
            var nameQuery = from user in db.Users
                            where user.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == "4ba13c9f-2403-45ad-961e-7c5cb6b08bc9")
                            orderby user.FirstName
                            select new
                            {
                                Id = user.Id,
                                Name = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName
                            };
            ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(nameQuery, "Id", "Name", selectedName);
            return View(document);
        }
```

view

```
@model IP3Latest.Models.Document

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>




@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Documents", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()



    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Document</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DocTitle, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DocTitle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DocTitle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RevisionNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RevisionNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RevisionNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.DropDownList("UserId")
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.TextBox("file", "", new { type = "file" }) <br />


            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

            @ViewBag.Message

        </div>  
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I checked all of the other questions about this and they all seemed to be a bit different so any help you could offer would be appreciated.

Comment: Because you do not populate the value of `ViewBag.UserId` before you return the view. But of the dozen ways you can create a `<select>` element using a `HtmlHelper` your have chosen the worst possible method (no type checking, no validation etc). Use a view model ([What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)) and remove your `Bind` attribute which means that `UserId` never has a value because you have excluded it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is right here:

```
catch
{
   ViewBag.Message = "File upload failed!!";
   return View(document);
}
```

When you run into an an error and the execution goes into the `catch` block, you are not setting the `UserId` property. Later your view looks for that property in this line:

```
@Html.DropDownList("UserId")
```

And since it cannot find it, it starts complaining. To fix it, you need to set the `UserId` property in the `catch` block as well. Having said that, a better question you may want to ask yourself is why you are ending up in the `catch` block? And since the block is a catch all block, you may have issues in your code anywhere in your `try` block.

The other issue is that once you have fixed the above, you will still have an issue because the `UserId` will be the name of the parameter submitted to the action method, not `selectedName` as you have in your action method.

Comment: wait @CodingYoshi so all I need to do is add  ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(nameQuery, "Id", "Name", selectedName); into the catch statement?, would it not also need to be in the try statement?

Comment: @kezanub What I am saying is that your view needs something and you are not providing it if you end up in the `catch` block. Use the debugger and find out why you are ending up in the `catch` in the first place. That means something is wrong.